# Numpy: sort by key function

Tags: python, function, sorting, numpy, key

Is there a way to sort the rows of a numpy ndarray using a key (or comparator) function, without resorting to converting to a python list?

In particular, I need to sort according to this function:

```
c1,c2= 4,7
lambda row: c1*(row[1]/c2)+row[0]
```

I realise one possible solution would be to generate a vector with the key value of each row, but how would one sort according to it? Should one seek to convert such vector into a index vector somehow?

```
order= c1*(matrix[:,1]/c2)+matrix[:,0]
indexes= order_to_index( order )
return matrix[ indexes ]
```

Is this realistic?

Comment: `order_to_index`? Do you mean [`argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)?

Comment: @wiso indeed! it never occurred to me that this is the same problem as giving the indexes that order the key value vector and sorting by it!

Comment: just try: `np.argsort([3,6,2,2,8]) #-> array([2, 3, 0, 1, 4])`. It doesn't sort your original input. Usually numpy functions don't have side effects

Comment: @wiso indeed, just did, I edited my last post in the meantime, sorry. Thank you! Will you consider adding an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your approach is right, it is similar to the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) or [Decorate-Sort-Undecorate (DSU) idiom](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate)

As I said you can use the numpy function [np.argsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html). It does the work of your `order_to_index`.

Answer (score 6):

For a more explicit answer, suppose we have an array `x` and want to sort the rows according to some function `func` which takes a row of `x` and outputs a scalar.

```py
x[np.apply_along_axis(func, axis=1, arr=x).argsort()]
```

For this example

```py
c1, c2 = 4, 7
x = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, -5]
])
x[np.apply_along_axis(lambda row: c1 * / c2 * row[1] + row[0], 1, x).argsort()]
```

Out:

```
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4, -5],
       [ 2,  3]])
```

In this case, `np.apply_along_axis` isn't even necessary.

```py
x[(c1 / c2 * x[:,1] + x[:,0]).argsort()]
```

Out:

```
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 4, -5],
       [ 2,  3]])
```