# How can this numpy 2D sorted array creation be optimized?

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, numpy

I have a NxM matrix called `coefficients` that I want to sort:

```
import numpy
N = 10
M = 42
coefficients = numpy.random.uniform(size=(N, M))
```

I have an array called `order` with `N` elements that says the order that the rows of `coefficients` should be in:

```
order = numpy.random.choice(range(N), N, False)
```

I'm sorting `coefficients` by sorting `order`:

```
coefficients = numpy.array([mag for (orig, mag)
                            in sorted(zip(order, coefficients),
                                      key=lambda pair: pair[0])])
```

This works, but it's probably slower than it should be. If this was in 1D, I'd use `fromiter`, but I don't know how to tackle this since it's 2D. Is there an optimization I can make here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, just `coefficients[order.argsort()]` is enough :)

See also [Numpy: sort by key function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877764/numpy-sort-by-key-function).

Comment: This goes in the opposite direction from the original code - the OP's code has `original[0]` go to `result[order[0]]` rather than having `result[0]` come from `original[order[0]]`. This might be an acceptable difference, depending on how `order` needs to behave. If not, we need `coefficients[order.argsort()]`.

Comment: (I don't know why the other guys deleted their answers. There are two deleted answers that already provide this information.)

Comment: Omg, so obvious. Thanks a bunch you two!

Comment: @JoeKington, he might have thought the same :D

Comment: It's also worth noting that if the sort gets expensive, `result = numpy.empty_like(coefficients); result[order] = coefficients` can avoid the sort. At the scale given in the question, it's not a problem, but with millions of rows, it becomes a big difference.