# How can I sort numpy array of colors by position value?

Tags: python, image, numpy, sorting

I have an array of available colors, let me say they are in the YCrCb space, I want to sort the array by the Y channel (the first channel) without mess with the color elements.

My array:

```
colors = np.array([[[191, 142, 109],
                    [196, 138, 116],
                    [193, 144, 111],
                    [198, 140, 118]]], dtype=np.uint8)

colors.shape
# (1, 4, 3)
```

My desired output:

```
array([[[191, 142, 109],
        [193, 144, 111],
        [196, 138, 116],
        [198, 140, 118]]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

#### What I've tried and It is not working

I was using `np.sort`. But I noticed If I do:

```
np.sort(colors, axis=2)
# array([[[109, 142, 191],
#         [116, 138, 196],
#         [111, 144, 193],
#         [118, 140, 198]]], dtype=uint8)
```

It doesn't reorder the elements, instead it reorders the channel's values of the elements.

Another tactic that I used:

```
np.sort(pallete.reshape(-1, 3), axis=0)
# array([[191, 138, 109],
#        [193, 140, 111],
#        [196, 142, 116],
#        [198, 144, 118]], dtype=uint8)
```

That one had misled me, it is quite similar to what I want, but it messes the colors elements.

---

Comment: Use argsort - `colors[:,colors[...,0].argsort()]`.

Comment: That's great @Divakar, thx. Put it in the answers.

Comment: Most probably is covered in at least one of the past answers on SO. We just need to find *the one*.

Comment: I agree with you, but I couldn't find it on the way I had the doubt, with the words that I have in mind to search it. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @Divakar depends how you search, if you define the right keyword for the problem, you can get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877764/numpy-sort-by-key-function) for example

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = np.array([[[191, 142, 109],
                    [196, 138, 116],
                    [193, 144, 111],
                    [198, 140, 118]]], dtype=np.uint8)
desired_output = np.array([[[191, 142, 109],
        [193, 144, 111],
        [196, 138, 116],
        [198, 140, 118]]], dtype=np.uint8)
print(colors.shape)
# (1, 4, 3)
```

My solution:

```
# get first column to collect only these value for easy sorting 
first_column = colors[:, :, 0]
print(first_column)
# [[[191]
#  [196]
#  [193]
#  [198]]]

# argsort method return with indices of the sorted elements of the first column
# argsort with 'mergesort' a stable sort that mean doesn't mess the column elements as expected
# axis=None mean the flattening of result, make a simple vector
indices = first_column.argsort(kind='mergesort', axis=None)
print(indices)
# [0 2 1 3] # it will be the first element by indices[0]==0 what 0 point to 191 in first column vector
#           # it will be the second element by indices[1]==2 what 2 point to 193 in first column vector and so on

# make indeed the colors arrays in sort by indices
my_output = colors[:, indices]
# check equality of your desired output and my output 
print(np.array_equal(desired_output, my_output))
# True

# the aboves' short form
print(colors[:, colors[:, :, 0].argsort(kind='mergesort', axis=None)])
# [[[191 142 109]
#  [193 144 111]
#  [196 138 116]
#  [198 140 118]]]
```

if you want to sort by column 0, then 1, then 2, please look at this link:
[Sorting arrays in NumPy by column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194077)